# Microsoft Graph API - how to create subscription to event in shared mailbox

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am following the doco on: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks

I want to create a subscription to call a webhook every time an event in a shared mailbox is created or updated.

I think it will be something like this below. Can anyone give me an example of how I can configure the RESOURCE parameter, to be my shared mailbox and events?

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "changeType": "created,updated",
  "notificationUrl": "https://mywebhook.com",
  "resource": "/me/mailfolders('inbox')/messages",
  "expirationDateTime": "2050-03-20T11:00:00.0000000Z",
  "clientState": "SecretClientState"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the resource parameter to `/users/yourSharedMailBox@yourTenant.com/events`